# Xcode5 iOS7 Segues + popViewControllerAnimated = broken transition

Tags: storyboard, ios7, segue, xcode5, popviewcontrolleranimated

So I took over an app from another developer and life was peachy in iOS 6.  Unfortunately they used a Storyboard + Segues to control the navigation of the app and it is a total mess.  The problem I'm having with iOS7 is when a user goes through a few segues and finishes, the app tries to navigate backwards using popViewControllerAnimated.

This code causes an error:

```
    ((PhotoCaptureViewController*) self.navigationController.viewControllers[self.navigationController.viewControllers.count - 2]).editedImage = _image;
    ((PhotoCaptureViewController*) self.navigationController.viewControllers[self.navigationController.viewControllers.count - 2]).popBack = YES;

    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

This code seems to navigate backwards just fine:

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Obviously I don't think the casting & trickery of going through the navigationController's viewController array is a good idea (especially without introspection) but why would this only cause an issue in iOS7?  In [Apple's iOS 7 Api Diffs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/iOS70APIDiffs/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013203) I don't see popViewControllerAnimated being deprecated so I'm at a loss.

I won't even mention how screwed up the layout of the Storyboard is, I'll spend my weekend fixing that PITA.